Sourcing shell file from Python
I am working on a code which does multiprocessing. For this, I want to source different files accordingly. I want to have the sourcing inside my Python file as I am not very keen on bash. I tried all the solutions outlined in the following post, but nothing worked for me. Before running the Python file I source the file such that echo $DETECTOR_PATH returns /data/tomble/eic/epic/install/share/epic. Now, I run the Python file and I copy the directory which holds the sh file:
    def copy_epic(self, curr_px_path):
        # copy epic to respective px folder for parameter reference 
        os.system(f'cp -r {self.det_dir} {curr_px_path}')    
        return os.path.join(curr_px_path, "epic")

and then I run a loop changing curr_px_path:
            # copy epic and compact folders (os.path.join(curr_px_path, "epic"))
            curr_px_epic_path = self.copy_epic(curr_px_path)

            print(f"curr_px_epic_path: {curr_px_epic_path}")

            # source current detector 
            self.source_px_epic(curr_px_epic_path + "/install/bin/thisepic.sh")

            print(f"os.environ['DETECTOR_PATH']: {os.environ['DETECTOR_PATH']}")

Using one of the solutions suggested in the post:
    def source_px_epic(self, current_px_epic_sh_path):
        command = shlex.split("bash -c f'source {current_px_epic_sh_path} && env'")
        proc = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
        for line in proc.stdout:
        (key, _, value) = line.partition("=")
        os.environ[key] = value
        proc.communicate()

        pprint.pprint(dict(os.environ))

But my prints suggest that this is not working:
curr_px_epic_path: /data/tomble/Analysis_epic_new/simulations/simEvents/2.0x0.1px/epic
os.environ['DETECTOR_PATH']: /data/tomble/eic/epic/install/share/epic

Since I copied the folder with the shell file, I wish to get
os.environ['DETECTOR_PATH']: /data/tomble/Analysis_epic_new/simulations/simEvents/2.0x0.1px/epic after sourcing.
I tried all the Python sourcing functions in the post I linked above. I am running thew file while in a singularity environment, and am running Ubuntu 24.04.01. What am I doing wrong?

How do you know that those sourced files are supposed to be movable like that? I mean, that just moving them ensure that they set up variables according to their position? Have you tried doing this by hand, in an interactive shell (copying the directory, and then source from the copy, and see if variables change? There is no rule about that. For all we know, install/bin/thisepic.sh could well contain hard coded DETECTOR_PATH=/data/tomble/eic/epic/install/share/epic

I see the suggestion of running the Python script from a bash script but for my case, using Python's multiprocessing to manage my program, I do not see how this could be applicable without rewriting the whole multiprocessing routine in bash which is a bit beyond my level currently.

@chrslg, you're right! I did test and it is as such. Thanks!

Plus, I must say, that seems to me to be a bad idea to try to "source from python". source in bash means that you are "importing" some bash code in another bash script (it is not all all the same as spawning a bash interpreter to execute some bash code: that can be done from any process, regardless of whether the parent process is itself coded in bash or not). So, what you are asking is a bit like "I would like to #include some c header file in my python script because I am not good at C`. Sure. you could (as the OP of your linked post) try to rewrite a C parser.

Or, as the main answer, reply "no, you should rely on existing C compiler instead", and do some Popen(gcc -E) tricks to try to use the C compiler to extract information from a .h. But at the end, you have no guarantee that it will do what you want, and, more importantly, you will end up have to do some C tricks at a level way more important than what you were trying to avoid in the first place. So, likewise, here, I am afraid that trying to do such "include bash in python" magic will force you to do way more bash than you want.
